# pfSense: dynamic DNS does not update automaticaly - it knows it's outdated

Tags: pfsense

I'm using dyndns with pfSense and I have a router connected on the WAN line (DHCP configuration). Every few days my ISP changes my IP but pfsense does not update it automatically.

If I open the WebUI and visit the dynamic DNS service it shows my IP in red color because it detects that it's not the current one. If I click "save and update" it correctly updates the IP.

How can I make pfSense automatically update the IP?

Answer (score 6):

It appears that this is a known limitation[1] when pfsense is connected with your modem/router using TCP/IP (either static or dynamic). The workaround is this:

Install the cron package (`System > Package Manager > Available Packages`, search for cron and click `INSTALL`). Then go to `Services > Cron` and click edit(the pencil) on the line about `rc.dyndns.update`. You need to change the Minute to `*/5` and Hour to `*`. This will make pfsense to check for IP changes every 5 minutes.

---

**Notes**
[1] There is a closed bug report https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/2148 where the pfsense team suggests this workaround. They note that "the cron package allows editing that easily, don't think it's worthwhile for us to bother"